# Android, how to use activitygroup with listview?

Tags: android, listview, tabbar

I have a tabbar in my app and there is a custom listview in the first tab page. i want to call new activity in the same tab when click the list items. I have searched two days and the only solution is to use activitygroup according to someone. But my first page class has "extends ListActivity" code to list my array thus i can not add "extends activitygroup" to this class. How can i use activitygroup without adding extends code?

Comment: Note that `ActivityGroup` is now deprecated. Please consider alternative strategies.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you tell me what kind of strategies can we use to replace ActivityGroup. Because most of my apps are making use of ActivityGroup.

Comment: But if you are using custom listview you need not make your class to extend activitygroup rite? your class can simply extend an Activity or activitygroup.

Comment: @CommonsWare , if it is not deprecated then how can i use tab bar when calling new intents. i want them in same tab bar.

Comment: @Andro Selva: Use fragments or views.

Comment: @caglar: You never needed `ActivityGroup` to use tabs. You can put views in tabs, for example (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab). Going forward, tabs are in the action bar on Honeycomb, typically using fragments. You can achieve the same functionality on previous versions of Android using ActionBarSherlock.